# GWT MVC + UIBinder

Tags: java, model-view-controller, gwt, uibinder

What's the easiest and simplest way to implement an MVC-style pattern using UIBinder for the UIs?

Comment: This is a really non-specific answer. Are you looking for tutorials on MVC or UIBinder? There are plenty out there if you google them.

Comment: All of the MVC examples with GWT don't use UIBinder and I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: The recommended pattern is MVP, are you sure that's not what you're referring to?

Comment: This is interesting. It is correct that MVP is usually the way to go, but the MVC question is a good one. If anyone is using it, and with UiBinder, it might be a good insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this blog post.](http://www.nieleyde.org/SkywayBlog/post.htm?postid=e49efd5b-31c8-423f-9fff-91c2ba6514ed)
It talks about using MVP and UIBinder together, and includes a sample app.  I think you'll find most people in the GWT arena talking about Model-View-Presenter (MVP) rather than MVC.

Answer (score 2):

See this: http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html
U Normally you use MVC  to fight spaghetti but Event bus manage is the favored GWT mode.

Answer (score 1):

With GWT, UiBinder is entirely within the "View".  The XML and Java file together are a view.  So UiBinder doesn't really ever deal with the Model and Controller, it's just the View.

Does this clear things up?